# How to read a pdf file from REST API using retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

This is my json data coming from backend. How to read this Pdf file using Retofit library.

Thanks in Advance

```
{
        "data": [
            {
                "Invoice": "Bhavdip-html-to-pdf (1).pdf"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: You need download and save your pdf then open your pdf using intent

Answer (score 0):

You must first Download your pdf file with

> Download Manager

after it, u can use this library for read it.

[Library for read pdf in java](https://www.mkyong.com/java/pdfbox-how-to-read-pdf-file-in-java/)

Notice :

***you must take a url of your pdf in json***

Answer (score 0):

see 
https://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-download-large-file-using-retrofit-streaming/

this is not a good scenario for large files .if your files are small you can use retrofit for downloading them but if your files are large you should use download manager for them.

above link help you for downloading file with retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

```
URL url = new URL( f_url[0] );//pass you url here
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream( url.openStream(), 1024 );

                // Output stream to write file
                String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File folder = new File( extStorageDirectory );

                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault() ).format( new Date() );
                String fileName = "SMART_" + timeStamp + "_" + Brochure.substring( Brochure.lastIndexOf( '/' ) + 1 );

                File file = new File( folder, fileName );
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream( file);

                byte[] data = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((read( data )) != -1) {
                   // writing data to file
                    output.write( data, 0, count );
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e( "Error: ", e.getMessage() );
            }
```

this is the way of download pdf file from the server